# wordpress error when upgrade php

Tags: php, wordpress

i have an error when my client upgrade php version to 5.3.24

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed:
>   unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1 in
>   /home/internet/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 258
>   [contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]

please help me to fix it.

thanks for read.

Comment: 404 Not Found is not related to PHP version. By the way, what is the WordPress version? and original PHP version?

Comment: i'm using wordpress version 3.5.1 and i don't know original php version, i only know currently php version when my client tell to me this error

Comment: `contact-form-7` is a WordPress plugin. Does it support WP 3.5.1 ? Does the plugin enabled? Is the file exist in `/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/` ?

Comment: yes. contact-form-7 support WP 3.5.1 and it is enable and exists on server. it is working before my client upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Looks like some problem in your Contact Form 7 plugin.

### 1: Go into the WP Admin Interface > Plugins and Disable Contact Form 7

What we're doing here is trying to isolate the problem. Seeing whether it is an issue with the Contact Form 7 Plugin, or something else.

### 2: Reload the Affected Page

If the Error is no longer present, the problem is inside the Plugin. (Go to #3.)
If the Error is still present, the problem is not inside the Plugin, if you could update the error message in your question to the new message seen, that would help.

### 3: Update the Plugin

If there is an update available for the plugin, upgrade it, then re-activate it and retest it.

### 4: If it's still a problem

The error message is suggesting that a parameter being handled for a `preg_replace()` call is incorrect. It would be a case of looking closely at each instance where the Contact Form 7 shortcode is used, as well as the function which is associated with that shortcode, to try and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that you get the same error, with other shortcodes? In that case, it sounds like either there is a problem with your Wordpress Install (in which case, you may need to reinstall it), or some of your code may be fouling the shortcode handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think this means that you lost that contact form and still using a shortcode for it.

Did they make any other changes?

Sounds like that contact-form-7 plugin is searching for a form that doesn't exist. Make sure you spelled and capitalized everything correctly inside the shortcode.

Comment: yes sure. i think it has error cause php version or PCRE. but i don't know how to fix it currently ?